# PyQt QTreeView checkable Column header, possible?

Tags: qt, header, qtreeview, columnheader

I have a TreeView class with a QStandarItemModel and I want to set one column in "chekeable mode" where if it is check then all item in that column are checked. A CheckAll check box in the column.